# Is it possible to avoid a lot of using statements?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, adapter

Lets say I have a simple code like this ([fiddleLink](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMQugr)):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Dependency register logic here
        var service = new DataServiceAdapter();
        var client = new Client(service);
        Foo(client);
    }

    //Work class
    public static void Foo(Client client)
    {
        client.ClientMethod();
    }
}

public class Client
{
    private readonly IDataService _service;
    public Client(IDataService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public void ClientMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_service.Method());
        Console.WriteLine(_service.Method2("Hello"));
    }
}

internal class DataServiceAdapter : IDataService
{
    public bool Method()
    {
        using (var something = new SpecifiDataService())
        {
            return something.Method();
        }
    }

    public int Method2(string arg)
    {
        using (var something = new SpecifiDataService())
        {
            return something.Method2(arg);
        }
    }
}

public class SpecifiDataService : IDataService, IDisposable
{
    public bool Method()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int Method2(string arg)
    {
        return arg.Length;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Dispose logic here
    }
}

public interface IDataService
{
    bool Method();
    int Method2(string arg);
}
```

Goal I want to achieve is to encapsulate `using` logic from client somewhere else (specifically in `DataServiceAdapter` class).

Is there any way to write `using` statement only once and not repeat it in every single method?

P.S. `SpecifiDataService` may be WCF client service or DbContext of EntityFramework. Both should have short lifespans so I cant just open connection once and work with it.

P.P.S I can't reuse `SpecificDataService` because in real case it will be WCF proxy-client or EntityFramework `DbContext` implementation. Both cases contains dozens of method calls, so I have to write `using` statements everywhere. First of all I want to free my client class from implementation of service. It should work both with short living services and long living ones. Another thing I tried to achieve - write methods without `using` because its boring copy-paste in every single method

Comment: Can you briefly describe the kind of cleanup action that will be performed by the `Dispose` method? If it is third-party code, please try your best to describe what it might do, according to your understanding. The purpose is to evaluate the tradeoffs of deferring the dispose, i.e. to keep the `IDataService` objects alive for a longer time, possibly across multiple function calls.

Comment: @rwong `SpecifiDataService` may be WCF client service or DbContext of EntityFramework. Both should have short lifespans so I cant just open connection once and work with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C#3+:

```
internal class DataServiceAdapter : IDataService
{
    public bool Method()
    {
        return Using(s => s.Method());
    }

    public int Method2(string arg)
    {
        return Using(s => s.Method2(arg));
    }

    private static TRes Using<TRes>(Func<SpecifiDataService, TRes> func)
    {
        using (var something = new SpecifiDataService())
        {
            return func(something);
        }
    }
}
```

C#6:

```
internal class DataServiceAdapter : IDataService
{
    public bool Method() => Using(s => s.Method());

    public int Method2(string arg) => Using(s => s.Method2(arg));

    private static TRes Using<TRes>(Func<SpecifiDataService, TRes> func)
    {
        using (var something = new SpecifiDataService())
            return func(something);
    }
}
```

Explanation: extract a command-pattern-like function and then reduce its arity via partial application.

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/30/currying-vs-partial-function-application

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327955/does-functional-programming-replace-gof-design-patterns

Comment: It would be a bunch of one-liners with C#6 by the way.

Comment: Could you show me please how it could be an one-liner in C#6?

Comment: @Szer ok, done.

Comment: Programmers is [about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) conceptual questions and answers are expected to _explain_ things. Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Comment: @gnat the question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com anyway and they allow code-only answers AFAIK. But I have made an effort to explain.

Comment: How is this writing using only once?

Comment: @JeffO the question says 'using statement'. I see only one of 'em in my code per language version.